# How to read get and responses from webbrowser in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, url, get

Is it possible to access to GET params of current url in my Windows.Control.Webbrowser? 
webBrowser.Resources.Source returns only Source, no other methods was found.
Or maybe is is possible to use Windows.Forms.Webbrowser in WPF instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a proxy and run everything through that while monitoring it in order to read the GET and Responses.
There are components that help you do that.

[Fiddler Core](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore) is one such.
They have examples on their website.

> Key Features
>
> HTTP and HTTPS traffic capture and modification. Powerful object model
>   for content filtering and modification. Store and reload web traffic.
>   Support for virtually any client application. Support for most devices
>   via mobile proxy settings.